# obtener la hora y minutos de un TimePickerDialog en frgaments android

Tags: android, android-fragment, alertdialog, textview

alguien sabe como obtener la Hora y el minuto de un `TimePickerDialog`?
Tengo dos botones en un fragmento uno que dispara un `DataPickerDialog` del cual obtengo muy bien la fecha y un botón que lanza un `TimePickerDialog` pero me da un error al dar aceptar una ves que se selecciono el tiempo seleccionado. Como puedo obtener el valor y que me lo muestre en un `TextView`.

[image: Los Dos Botones en un fragment]

[image: Cuando pulso en ok me sale el error:]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí les dejo mi código:

```
public class AgendaFragment extends Fragment {
    public AgendaFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setActionbarTitle("Horario");
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_agenda, container, false);

        Button btime = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btntime);
        Button bdate = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btndate);
        Button bsen = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnsend);

        final TextView datvi = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.viewdate);
        final TextView tievi = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.viewti);
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        final int hora = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        final int minuto = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        bdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Calendar calendario = Calendar.getInstance();
                int yy = calendario.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int mm = calendario.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int dd = calendario.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                DatePickerDialog datePicker = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                        String fecha = String.valueOf(year) + "-" + String.valueOf(monthOfYear)
                                + "-" + String.valueOf(dayOfMonth);
                        datvi.setText(fecha);
                    }
                }, yy, mm, dd);

                datePicker.show();
            }
        });

        btime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Calendar getDate = Calendar.getInstance();

                TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                        getDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
                        getDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                        SimpleDateFormat timeformat=new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm a");
                        timeformat.format(getDate.getTime());
                        tievi.setText((CharSequence) timeformat);
                    }
                }, getDate.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), getDate.get(Calendar.MINUTE), false);

                timePickerDialog.show();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error esta en esta parte de aquí amigo.

```
btime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final Calendar getDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                getDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
                getDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                SimpleDateFormat timeformat=new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm a");
                timeformat.format(getDate.getTime());
                tievi.setText((CharSequence) timeformat);
            }
        }, getDate.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), getDate.get(Calendar.MINUTE), false);

        timePickerDialog.show();
    }
});
```

En especifico en la línea de código

```
timeformat.format(getDate.getTime());
```

el método timeformat.format() te regresa una `string` con la fecha en el formato deseado, pero aquí no asignas ese retorno a ninguna variable. Por lo cual luego cuando deseas convertir este `timeFormat` a `string`, la aplicación se detiene porque eso no tiene sentido. Cambia el código de la siguiente manera

```
btime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final Calendar getDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                getDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
                getDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                SimpleDateFormat timeformat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm a");
                String formatedDate = timeformat.format(getDate.getTime());
                tievi.setText(formatedDate);
            }
        }, getDate.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), getDate.get(Calendar.MINUTE), false);

        timePickerDialog.show();
    }
});
```

Eso debería arreglar el problema, espero te sirva.

Comment: Muy bueno hermano gracias!.